# How to show subclass in Report Viewer - VS 2010

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I am creating small application where I have done with Business Class. Now, I want to create report.
Firstly, Here is my Property Class :

```
 public class Property
    {
        public int PropertyId { get; set; }
        public int OwnerId { get; set; }

       //User is another Class
        public User Owner { get; set; }

        public int StaffUserId { get; set; }
        public Staff StaffPerson { get; set; }

        public string Address { get; set; }
        public int NoGarage { get; set; }
        public int NoRoom { get; set; }
        public int NoToilet { get; set; }
        public string PropertyType { get; set; }
        public string PropertyStatus { get; set; }
        public double SalePrice { get; set; }

        public double RentPricePerMonth { get; set; }
        public bool IsAvailable { get; set; }
...............
```

And Here is my User Class :

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
```

---

Now I want to create report using Property class and also want to show User class.
I am able to show objects of Property class but not able to show User Class.

How can I do this?

Currently I am generating report using this :

```
        Property p = Property.GetPropertyByPropertyId(propertyId);
        PropertyBindingSource.DataSource = p;
        reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Answer (score 0):

1.implement the Serializable interface to "User" class

```
  [Serializable]
     public class User
     {
```

2.If, in case you want to display the user name,

In the design of the report, the expression of the item  set a

> =Fields!Owner.Value.UserName